# SCSS pass separate sizes

Tags: css, sass

So I'm learning to use scss more and I'm having some trouble understanding certain things and wanted to see if anyone has some assistance for me.

So I have the following font-family defined:

```
h1, h2, h3 {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}
```

How can I expand that and define sizes for different headings like have different sizes for h1, h2 and h3? Would I need to start another declaration and use `h2 {` all over again?

Comment: You’ll have to start a new declaration with just the h2 if you only want to target that specific element.

Comment: Thanks @DanMullin, wasn't sure if SCSS was able to pass internal declarations or so, will just declare a new h2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can even automate that entirely, and even go exponentally, if you'd use a `pow()` function.

```
@mixin headings($base) {
  @for $i from 1 through 6 {
    h#{(6 + 1) - $i},
    .h#{(6 + 1) - $i} {
      font-size: #{$base + (($base / 2) * $i)};
    }
  }
}

@include headings(16px);
```

This will compile to:

```css
h6,
.h6 {
  font-size: 24px;
}

h5,
.h5 {
  font-size: 32px;
}

h4,
.h4 {
  font-size: 40px;
}

h3,
.h3 {
  font-size: 48px;
}

h2,
.h2 {
  font-size: 56px;
}

h1,
.h1 {
  font-size: 64px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Heading1</h1>
<h2>Heading2</h2>
<h3>Heading3</h3>
<h4>Heading4</h4>
<h5>Heading5</h5>
<h6>Heading6</h6>
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, like this:

```
h1{
font-size: 24px
}
h2{
font-size: 20px;
}
h3{
font-size: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add new declaration such as `h1{}` to `style.scss`, but there is a clever way to add this style quickly. You can use mixin h in the anywhere inside the `style.scss`. Please follow this:

// `_mixin.scss`

```
@mixin h($heading,$font){
  @if($heading==1){
    h1{font-size: $font + px;}
  }@else if($heading==2){
    h2{font-size: $font + px;}
  }@else if($heading==3){
    h3{font-size: $font + px;}
  }@else if($heading==4){
    h4{font-size: $font + px;}
  }@else if($heading==5){
    h5{font-size: $font + px;}
  }@else if($heading==6){
    h6{font-size: $font + px;}
  }
}
```

// style.scss

```
body{
  @include h(1,100);
  @include h(2,50);
  @include h(3,40);
  @include h(4,30);
}
```

// Output

```
body h1 {
  font-size: 100px; }
body h2 {
  font-size: 50px; }
body h3 {
  font-size: 40px; }
body h4 {
  font-size: 30px; }
```

Comment: Thanks @Sh.Sabour! This is incredible help! I'm still learning so this will be super useful.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished without mixins by using the `@extend` directive.

Not as powerful as the mixin in the other answer, but nice clean and simple.

```
%font {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
h1 {
    @extend %font;
    font-size: 20px;
}
h2 {
    @extend %font;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

This will be compiled as:

```
h1, h2 {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 20px;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```